# Windows version of mean.io expects mv command

Tags: mean.io

### Input:

```
mean init myfirst.js
```

### Output:

What would you name your mean app? myfirstv12

On Windows platform
Please check permissions independently
All permissions should be run with the local users permissions
Cloning branch: master into destination folder: myfirstv12
git clone  --depth 1  -b
master https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git "myfirstv12"
Cloning into 'myfirstv12'...
Added the "remote" upstream origin
'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Do you want to set up an admin user?
? Yes N

---

I get this error when installing my app using the mean command:

'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I can't find mv executable in Windows. Is there one?

Comment: please spend 2 minutes having a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Don't use html

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a folder by the same name already in the same directory. This error comes when you try deleting or replacing an existing folder. If you have one then delete it manually and try again. And try naming your sample application without special characters ("." in this case).